# "link" or "is linked with"

Tags: passive-voice

> Thailand links with Malaysia on the mainland of Asia.

If I change this sentence into passive:

> Malaysia is linked with Thailand.

Can the verb "link" be used in "passive" voice? Does it differ from the original meaning "connect with"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use **link** in the passive voice, and in fact it sounds more fluent and natural to use it that way:

> Thailand is linked to Malaysia

([Also, we usually say "linked *to*", not "linked *with*".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=linked%20to%2Clinked%20with&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clinked%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clinked%20with%3B%2Cc0))
For example,

> [Presently, Thailand **is linked to** its neighbors through an extensive and functioning network of roads, waterways, and air routes.](https://www.thailand-business-news.com/news/headline/49705-crossroads-mainland-southeast-asia-thailands-logistic.html)

The difference in meaning is the same as for any active vs. passive voice.  **Thailand links** means that Thailand specifically does something that links something else.  **Thailand is linked** means that something else is performing the action of linking on Thailand.

[The definition of the verb *link* is](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/link)

> to couple or connect by or as if by a link

So it makes more sense to say that (for example), the [Channel Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_Tunnel) **links** England and France, because the tunnel is the thing that does the connecting, or that England and France **are linked by** the tunnel, because the tunnel connects them.  But "England links to France" is unidiomatic.